# UITableView bug when returning textField

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I use this code to change first responder from one textField to another. Each text field tag = row + 100
Like tag of first textField(second row) = 101
Code works:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()
    let nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    // Try to find next responder
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: nextTag-100, inSection: 0))
    if(cell == nil)
    {

        return false
    }
    let nextResponder = cell!.viewWithTag(nextTag) as UIResponder!
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    if (nextResponder != nil){
        // Found next responder, so set it.

        nextResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

    }
    return false // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

To change navigation bar I use this code:

```
func setNavigationBar()
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.fromColor(.whiteColor()), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("REGISTRATION_TITLE", comment: "")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "cross_exit"), style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain , target: self, action: "getBackToAuth")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = self.specificGrayColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17)!]
}
```

But

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom
```

effect disappears after returning...

[before I tap next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tJFw.png)
[After I tap done when filled in last textField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxIOY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by the IQKeyboardSwift lib.
You may try

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
}
```

Hope will help you.